# Is there a way to make an image of a single volume at a point in time?

Tags: virtualization

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 box that I need to be able to re-image at any given point. With VMWare, is it possibly to create a snapshot or image of only a specific drive at a point in time?

Also, would this cause any performance overhead for the image to be maintained?

Comment: If this is a production machine, running off a snapshot is bad practice, just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Vmware ESXi, you should just be able to right click on the instance, and create a snapshot.  It will take up the obvious disk space, and while the image is being created CPU/Disk/Memory usage.